# "Cannot resolve symbol baoyz" Android Studio using baoyongzhang's SwipeMenuListView

Tags: android, git, import

I've recently downloaded the github repo: https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView
Which allows to be a SwipeMenuListView. But the "baoyz" in the following import methods is red:

```
import com.boayz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenu;
import com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuCreator;
import com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuItem;
import com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuLayout;
import com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView;
import com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView.OnMenuItemClickListener;
import com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView.OnSwipeListener;
```

And all the Stuff I added (SwipeMenu,SwipeMenuCreator,SwipeMenuItem,SwipeMenuLayout,etc.) that are in the following code are also red:

```
 SwipeMenuCreator creator = new SwipeMenuCreator() {

    @Override
    public void create(SwipeMenu menu) {
        // create "open" item
        SwipeMenuItem openItem = new SwipeMenuItem(
                getApplicationContext());
        // set item background
        openItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xC9, 0xC9,
                0xCE)));
        // set item width
        openItem.setWidth(dp2px(90));
        // set item title
        openItem.setTitle("Open");
        // set item title fontsize
        openItem.setTitleSize(18);
        // set item title font color
        openItem.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
        // add to menu
        menu.addMenuItem(openItem);

        // create "delete" item
        SwipeMenuItem deleteItem = new SwipeMenuItem(
                getApplicationContext());
        // set item background
        deleteItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xF9,
                0x3F, 0x25)));
        // set item width
        deleteItem.setWidth(dp2px(90));
        // set a icon
        deleteItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete);
        // add to menu
        menu.addMenuItem(deleteItem);
    }
};
```

Help appreciated! (Yes, I've downloaded the repo. But The only thing I did to it was extract it)

Comment: I'm using android studio

Comment: Did you just copy and paste the files?

Comment: @Zain which files? Explain to me what to do plz?

Comment: Are you just trying to run the sample repo code? Clean build, and see if that work.

Comment: @Zain no I am not trying to run the sample code. The samlple code gives me an error when trying to run it. So what I did was copy the code in the activity_main file and pasted it in a new activity, and added some stuff in the layout file.

Comment: You need to have reference to the import classes somewhere in your project, create a folder, but all the reference classes in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a package `boayz` - Copy + paste these [files](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView/tree/master/library/src/com/baoyz/swipemenulistview) into this package.

Ensure each file builds and you have the correct imports etc.

Then ensure the project builds and hopefully it will run. It would have been easier for you to take the repo and see if you can run the samples.

Comment: Where do I create the package? Thanks for your interest in helping me; hope I'm not annoying you

Comment: In your src folder, where the other classes/packages are located. If you're new to Android look at Udacity Android course.

Comment: I tried running the samples but Android Studio gives me an error. #WhyIsItSoHard

Comment: @Zain  can u ppls help me how can i add loadMore items in listview onScrollListener using SwipeMenuListview i have to show user delete button on swipe everyitem of listview which is working fine now have to add loadMore items on scroll and pull to refresh listview

Comment: I created package com.baoyz.swipemenulistview and copied all files into package.
It works like a charm for me.